# How to get power usage for an app?

Tags: java, android

I have a program collecting wifi, acceleration, scan bluetooth and sometimes communicate with server. Does anybody know how to get power usage(voltage, current and power) of each component and the power usage of overall system?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API for this in the Android SDK.

You can purchase a Qualcomm MDP device with the [Trepn power profiler](http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/development-devices/trepn-profiler). This costs 1,000 USD, last I looked.

You can also try [PowerTutor](http://ziyang.eecs.umich.edu/projects/powertutor/documentation.html). I have not experimented with this yet but plan to in the coming months.

Or, you can examine the output from the Settings battery screen, if your app is showing up there.